# Spring Security OAuth2 accessToken

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

In my Spring Boot application I need to programmatically create a new user and obtain OAuth2 access/refresh tokens for him from internal(part of this application) OAuth2 Authorization Server.

Then, I plan to send these `access/refresh tokens` to some external (client) application that will interact with my first application on behalf of this user.

Is it possible to programmatically obtain OAuth2 access/refresh tokens for this user without providing password(during the programmatic creation of this user I don't want to deal with `password`, only `username`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, take a look at the code below

```
@Autowired
private TokenEndpoint tokenEndpoint;

public ResponseEntity<?> createToken(User user) {

        Principal principal = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());

        HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        parameters.put("client_id", "XXX");
        parameters.put("client_secret", "XXX");
        parameters.put("grant_type", "password");
        parameters.put("password", user.getPassword());
        parameters.put("scope", "XXX");
        parameters.put("username", user.getUserName());

        return tokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(principal, parameters);
}
```

but you are violating the OAuth2 spec. Authorization should be performed by Resource Owner.